# Spring Boot 401 Unauthorized on POST request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, postman, http-status-code-401

I have an app, with configured security, that uses basic authentication (login + password).
My main trouble is when I do a `POST` request in Postman, I receive `401 Unauthorized`. But when I do the same request but change it to `GET` request, it's returning data with status `200`. Here is my security configuration with additional screenshots.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity {

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/login";
    private static final String LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL = "/login";
    private static final String LOGIN_FAILURE_URL = "/login?error";
    private static final String LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL = "/";
    private static final String DENIED_PAGE_URL = "/404";

    private final UserService userService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public SecurityConfiguration(UserService userService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/login", "/register").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/public/**").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/icons/**").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/images/**").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/private/**").authenticated();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "SUPER_ADMIN");
                })
                .formLogin(loginForm -> {
                    loginForm.loginPage(LOGIN_URL);
                    loginForm.loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL);
                    loginForm.failureUrl(LOGIN_FAILURE_URL);
                })
                .logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL))
                .exceptionHandling(e -> {
                    e.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
                    e.accessDeniedPage(DENIED_PAGE_URL);
                })
                .httpBasic();

        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

}
```

This is my request

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public Expense saveExpense(@RequestBody ExpenseRequest expenseRequest) {
    Expense expense = expenseConvertor.convertToExpense(expenseRequest);
    return expenseService.saveExpense(expense);
}
```

[image: Post image]

GET Request

[image: GET image]

**Additional Information**

- Any other `GET` requests with provided auth in header works fine
- `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE` requests, all throws `401 Unauthorized`

Any help will be great, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you are dealing with a CSRF error, the fastest way to know what is happening is to add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` to your `application.properties` and analyze your logs.

You have disabled CSRF protection in the second line of the `SecurityConfiguration#configure(HttpSecurity)` method, but, a few lines below, you are calling `super.configure(http);`, which in turn [configures CSRF protection](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/217f89c4546e8464939727b0a1533457a9df7769/vaadin-spring/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/spring/security/VaadinWebSecurity.java#L182C6-L182C6) again. Try deleting that line or providing a CSRF token.

Answer (score 2):

Instaed of ***http.csrf().disable()*** u should use  ***http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers( "/url1/**","/url2/**"))*** to let csrf know that u want to ignore perticular Apis calls,
we dont use **disable()** this is provided by spring security itself to protect application from unwanted threats happens using browser cookies

Answer (score 0):

only GET passing usually happens because of csrf, seeing that you are disabling it. I think you should save security config file and restart your application.

Comment: I tried restarting app but still can't process `POST` requests, maybe I'm missing something else

Comment: once I have the time I will try to recreate the same project and debug it